# Bold Text in RichTextBox similar to word pad

Tags: c#

I am developing a small text editor, I want text bold feature similar to MS Word and Wordpad.

- If I select bold then text should be written in bold.
- If I de-select bold then text should be regular
- If I select some text and press bold it should be bold and rest of the text should remain regular.
- If I select already bold text and select bold then it should become regular.

I have tried the following code from MSDN but its not working the way I want. Kindly help.

```
    if (richTextBox.SelectionFont != null)
    {
            System.Drawing.Font currentFont = richTextBox.SelectionFont;
            System.Drawing.FontStyle newFontStyle;

            if (richTextBox.SelectionFont.Bold == true)
            {
                newFontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
            }
            else
            {
                newFontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
            }

            richTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(
               currentFont.FontFamily,
               currentFont.Size,
               newFontStyle
            );
        }
```

Comment: If you want to change the Font in general, use "richTextBox.Font" instead so that any text typed after selecting this will become Bold.

Comment: The code should work for the case of a valid selection. If nothing is selected you toggle richTextBox.Font instead of richTextBox.SelectionFont, just as Rarilou told you.